# Add myself to CC list for a Google Docs

Tags: google-workspace, google-docs

My coworker created a Google Docs that several people are adding comments to. However, currently I don't get emails / notifications when the comments are added, and I have to keep reopening the page to see any new comments.

Is there any way for me to sign myself up to get these notifications, or a way for my coworker to do so for me?